# i have a JSON and trying to parse with objectMapper. But mapper gives me a nil

Tags: arrays, swift

```
  {
    "name": "a",
    "enabled": true,
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "enabled": true,
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "name": "c",
    "enabled": false,
    "available": true
  },
  {
    "name": "f",
    "enabled": false,
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "name": "g",
    "enabled": false,
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "name": "h",
    "enabled": false,
    "available": false
  }
```

```
class CallsResponse: Response, Mappable {
    
    var name: String?
    var enabled: Bool?
    var available: Bool?
    
    required init?(map: Map) {
    }
    
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.name <- map["name"]
        self.enabled <- map["enabled"]
        self.available <- map["available"]
    }

}
```

// and trying parse

```
func parseResponse(data: Data) throws -> ResponseType? {
    if let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] {
        return Mapper<ResponseType>().map(JSON: JSON)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Mapper...  I have never even heard of it.

Comment: @ElTomato it's [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper).

Comment: That is not the complete json and my guess is that you have an array of dictionaries so try `as? [[String: Any]]`

Comment: You also need to include `ResponseType` in your question.

Comment: Since Swift 4 third-party libraries like `SwiftyJSON` and `ObjectMapper` have become obsolete in favor of `Codable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Array of dictionaries try to type cast as [[String: Any]]

Now there is no need of external mapper frameworks Apple is providing **Codable** which is easy to use and easy to understand the errors in parsing as well.